# regexp for phone number?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I need to build a regexp for phone numbers, such as:

> +79261234567 
>   +7 926 123 45 67
>   89261234567
>   79261234567
>   8(926)123-45-67
>   9261234567
>   79261234567
>   89261234567
>   8-926-123-45-67
>   8 927 1234 234
>   8 927 12 12 888
>   8 927 12 555 12
>   8 927 123 8 123

I came now to this regexp:

`/((8|\+7)[\- ]?)((\(?9\d{2}\)?[\- ]?)[\d\- ]{7,10})?[\d\- ]{10,10}/g`

[link to regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/#/%28%288%7C%5C+7%29%5B%5C-%20%5D?%29%28%28%5C%28?9%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C%29?%5B%5C-%20%5D?%29%5B%5Cd%5C-%20%5D%7B7,10%7D%29?%5B%5Cd%5C-%20%5D%7B10,10%7D/g)

But it's not correctly working.So any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there any format for these numbers? or just 11 numbers with posible (, - and whitespace?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions here. Have none of those answers helped?

Comment: There's a solution provided by the community of Regexr: http://www.regexr.com/38pvb

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) which deals with this issue and is pretty clearly answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var input  = 'phone number',
    output = input.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, '$1').replace(/(^\+)|[- ]+/g, ''),
    result = /^\d{10,11}$/.test(output);
```

Explanation:

```
\(([^)]+)\) - looks for digits with brackets around them to be removed
(^\+)|[- ]+ - looks for starting `+` or whitespace/dash in number to be removed
^\d{10,11}$ - checks if number has exacly 10 to 11 digits
```